# Mapbox markers throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

I´m trying to add markers to my map from mapbox.

This is my Angular TypeScript code.

```
export class MappViewComponent implements OnInit {
  map: mapboxgl.Map;
  lat = 41.1293;
  lng = -8.4464;
  style = "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11";
  zoom = 8;

  constructor(
    private mapService: MapService,
    private nodeService: NodeService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildMap(this.map);
    /*var mymap = L.map('mapID').setView([41.260555, -8.436098], 10);
    this.buildMap(mymap);*/
    this.addMarkersLines(this.map);
    new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([this.lng, this.lat]).addTo(this.map);
  }

  /**https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html */
  buildMap(map: any) {
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      accessToken:
        "accessToken",
      container: "mapID",
      style: this.style,
      zoom: this.zoom,
      center: [this.lng, this.lat],
      antialias: true,
      attributionControl: false,
    });
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
```

The problem is that, after running in console it throws this error on this line:

```
new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([this.lng, this.lat]).addTo(this.map);
```

ERROR TypeError: t is undefined
addTo mapbox-gl.js:35
ngOnInit mapp-view.component.ts:30

Does anyone  have this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the error occurs since `this.map` is `undefined` here:

```
new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([this.lng, this.lat]).addTo(this.map);
                                                            ^^^^^^^^  
                                                            undefined
```

The way how function `buildMap` is implemented, it does *not* affect the object passed, meaning `this.map` stays `undefined` in your case. Try to refactor `buildMap` function, for example:

```
buildMap() {
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      accessToken: MAPBOX_TOKEN,
      container: 'mapID',
      style: this.style,
      zoom: this.zoom,
      center: [this.lng, this.lat],
      antialias: true,
      attributionControl: false,
    });
    this.map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
 }
```

Usage

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.buildMap();
    new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat([this.lng, this.lat]).addTo(this.map);
}
```